# WearableListenerService, onDataChanged() called only when watch is active

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am doing watchface and I am experimenting following issue : method onDataChange() on watch is only called when my watchface is on. When it is shaded or in ambient data are not fetched. How can I make watch accept changed data when not active?

Edit: It turned out it was my mistake. Code was removing listeners in onVisiabilityChange()

Comment: Are you calling `setUrgent()` on your `PutDatRequest` (on the handheld)? If you don't, the data changes may take up to half an hour to propagate - and although I haven't seen this behavior myself, it wouldn't surprise me if it this applied only when the watch is in ambient.

Comment: @String Unfortunately it does not help. Watch get data instantly when active but when screen is off data won't be fetched.

Comment: Then you probably need to add the relevant snippets of your code to your question. This isn't the normal behavior of the Data API, so without seeing what you're doing, nobody here can do more than guess (as I did with `setUrgent()`).

Comment: @String Yep it was my fault. Code was removing listener in onVisibilityChange.